# Python choice in an ordered array, picking value one after another

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am trying to do a simple process on python, I know there is an answer out here on how to achieve this, but I can't seem to find it.

Python should make selection from a list of data on a txt file, but in an ordered form. Say it would pick the first value when prompted, then the second value,and so on until the list is exhausted.

Is there a way to achieve this without random?  The only way I have seen so far are randomly, and randomly without/with replacement. The order of choice is very important here.

```
              import random
              with open ("questions.txt","r") as f:
              question = f.readlines()
              post = (random.choice(question).strip())
              print (post)
```

The code above only do so randomly and not what I want, I want it ordered and stop when the list is finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open ("questions.txt","r") as f:
    question = f.readlines()
for each in question:
    print(each.strip())
```

or if you want to have more control, you can use `next` on an *Iterator* (and handle the end-of-iteration exception):

```py
with open ("questions.txt","r") as f:
    questions = iter(f.readlines())

while True:
    try:
        question = next(questions)
    except StopIteration:
        # no more questions
    else:
        # handle `question`
```